# Angular factory function throwing error claiming it isn't a function in Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I have seen a couple of questions like this before but they are usually clearly missing injections, and hopefully that isn't the case with my problem.

As part of my app I am making I am trying to make a get request to the server to return a list of modules.

### Controller

```
app.controller('ModulesCtrl', ['$scope','modFact','quizIndexFactory', '$http', function($scope, $http, quizIndexFactory, modFact){

$scope.moduleSet;
$scope.status;

getModules();

function getModules(){
    modFact.getList()
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.moduleSet = response.data;
        }, function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'unable to load modules in controller: ' + error.message;
        });
}
```

### Factory

```
app.factory('modFact', ['$http', function($http){
var modFact = {};

modFact.getList = function() {
    console.log("success");
    return $http.get('http://localhost:3000/module');
};

return modFact;
}]);
```

Yet I get the error pointing to the function call in the controller:

> Error: modFact.getList is not a function

Any ideas? I am following the structure provided by this blog post:
http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/using-an-angularjs-factory-to-interact-with-a-restful-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the order of arguments being injected into the controller does not match the order that you supply the arguments.  In your controller, the entity that is named `modFact` is actually angular's `$http` service (which doesn't have a `getList` method).

(Taking a little liberty with indentation and newlines to demonstrate the problem):

```
[       '$scope','modFact','quizIndexFactory', '$http',
function($scope, $http, quizIndexFactory, modFact) {
    ...
}]
```

should be:

```
[       '$scope', '$http', 'quizIndexFactory', 'modFact',
function($scope, $http, quizIndexFactory, modFact) {
    ...
}]
```

Comment: I had no idea the order of the arguments/injections mattered. Is that a totally obvious thing? Should I delete this question in shame? (Thank you so much, that fixed it)

Comment: @StraySheep -- I don't know that it's totally obvious to newcomers.  After all, you can drop the array entirely and it still works if you aren't minifying the code.  The reason you need it is because most people pump the code through a minifier which will mangle the names.  You write the name as `quizIndexFactory` and the minifier turns it into `a`.  The order matters so that angular can know what `a` is even after the minifier has done it's job.

Comment: ah that makes sense. Well yeah I'll keep it up. Wish I could give you the upvote, I appreciate the speedy response.